# "All" value gives me : pq: syntax error at or near "," in grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb, timescaledb

I am migrating my DB from InfluxDB to TimescaleDB.

In influx, I have 3 filters Operation, Meter, CP. All have 'all' , and it works fine when I select them.

In my queries, I have simple conditions:

When I try to convert it to TimescaleDB, I define the same filters, with 'all' options:

Then, with my query:

```
SELECT time_bucket('30 minutes', time) AS "time",
  sum(delta), meter_id
FROM measures
WHERE
  $__timeFilter("time") AND
  operation_id = $operationId AND
  source = $source
GROUP BY time, meter_id
ORDER BY time;
```

This query is working great when I select a value for operation_id.

But as long as I set him as `all`, I get:

```
 pq: syntax error at or near ","
```

Why is it happening, and how should I do to fix it ? I use grafana 7.0.5

Answer (score 2):

I finally could do it:

I used the button: `Generated SQL` that was converting `all` field to a list of values. So I changed `=` with `IN` and now I got it working.

```
SELECT time_bucket('30 minutes', time) AS "time",
  sum(delta), meter_id
FROM measures
WHERE
  $__timeFilter("time") AND
  meter_id IN ($meter_id) AND
  source = $source
GROUP BY time, meter_id
ORDER BY time;
```